# JComments send button not working

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have tried registering on their website to access the forums but the verification email won't come through so I have come here to ask.

The easiest way of explaining is showing you this image

[image]

As you can see, the text isn't inside the button. So the comment is posted if you click on the word but not when you click on the button.

I'm running Joomla 3.2.3 and an up to date version of Jcomments.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element with a tool such as Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools? Might be a CSS issue

Comment: @Lodder that's probably a good idea, it's just I disabled right click on our website. I guess I best turn it off first :P

Comment: You can also press `F12` to enable the Inspector :)

Comment: @Lodder I'm not seeing any errors, infact, it doesn't seem to be showing any html for that comment. Could that be because it's an extension?

Comment: No, any structural feature you see on your site should show up as HTML in the inspector. I remember using JComments on some older sites and didn't see to have any issues like this. Would you be able to provide a link to the site or a dev site? Also, does this occur on all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: @Lodder http://www.ultimatemuscleperformance.co.uk/index.php/component/allvideoshare/video/popular/challenge-punch-bag-situp-challenge

It seems to happen on all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see the problem. It's due to the line height being set to the `.btn` class in your template css file. To get around this, add the following to your template.css file:

```
#comments-form .btn, #comments-report-form .btn {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

This will ensure that everything is aligned properly :)

Comment: You blummin genius! Thank you so much :)